# Create Multiple PDF files from FPDF

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

What I'm trying to do is create and email multiple PDF files using FPDF. I already have everything working to email a single file but when I try to stick everything into a loop, the script ends up outputting only the first instance of the PDF then exits to a blank screen. this runs perfectly when I'm only processing one record, however when you add multiple, it only runs a single time. I really can't figure out what to do here is my code. Any assistance or direction is appreciated.

```
while ($data = mysql_fetch_row($query)) // under normal circumstances working properly
    {
        $clientid = $data['0'];
        if($clientid)
        {
            require("generatepdf.php"); //styles the pdf and is working properly
            $savepath = 'c:/ledgers/'.$cname.' Cash Ledger.pdf';
            $pdf->Output($savepath,'F');
            require("ledgeremail.php"); //runs query to get email address and emails the outputted file 
        }
    }
```

Here is the gist of my pdf generating code, the specifics of the generation left out.

```
<?php

require("includes/pdf/fpdf.php");


{

$pdf = new FPDF( );
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',16);

    //Run Query to get Ledger information for the $clientid variable
            //Pass information from query into the different variables throughout script



            //Print Document Title
            $pdf->Cell(0,10,$cname.' Petty Cash Ledger', 0,1,'L');
            //Print First Month Grouping
            $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
            $pdf->Line($linestart,$pdf->GetY(),$lineend,$pdf->GetY());
            $pdf->Cell(10,5,$startmonth.", ".$startyear, 0,0,'L');
            $pdf->SetX(175);
            $pdf->SetFont('','B');
            $pdf->Cell(20,5,'Balance Forward: $'.$balforward, 0,1,'R');
            $pdf->SetFont('');
            //print group headers
            $pdf->SetTextColor(101,102,102);
            $pdf->Cell(30,5,'Date',0,0,'L');
            $pdf->SetX(30);
            $pdf->Cell(105,5,'Description', 0,0,'L');
            $pdf->SetX(135);
            $pdf->Cell(20,5,'Deposit', 0,0,'R');
            $pdf->SetX(155);
            $pdf->Cell(20,5,'Withdrawl', 0,0,'R');
            $pdf->SetX(175);
            $pdf->Cell(20,5,'Balance', 0,1,'R');
            $pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0);
            $pdf->SetFillColor(255);

            while($ledger = mysql_fetch_row($ledgerqry))
            {
                if ($grey == 1) $pdf->SetFillColor(225);

                $currentmonth = date('F',strtotime($data[0]));
                if ($currentmonth != $startmonth)
                {
                    $pdf->SetFillColor(255);
                    $grey = 0;
                    $currentyear = date('Y',strtotime($data[0]));
                    //Print Month End Balance
                    $pdf->SetX(175);
                    $pdf->SetFont('','B');
                    $pdf->Cell(20,5,'Ending Balance: '.$runningbal, 0,1,'R',1);
                    $pdf->SetFont('');
                    $pdf->Line($linestart,$pdf->GetY()+2,$lineend,$pdf->GetY()+2);
                    //Print Month Grouping
                    $pdf->Cell(10,10,$currentmonth.", ".$currentyear, 0,0,'L');
                    $pdf->SetX(175);
                    $pdf->SetFont('','B');
                    $pdf->Cell(20,10,"Balance Forward: ".$runningbal, 0,1,'R');
                    $pdf->SetFont('');


                    //print group headers
                    $pdf->SetTextColor(101,102,102);
                    $pdf->Cell(30,5,'Date',0,0,'L');
                    $pdf->SetX(30);
                    $pdf->Cell(105,5,'Description', 0,0,'L');
                    $pdf->SetX(135);
                    $pdf->Cell(20,5,'Deposit', 0,0,'R');
                    $pdf->SetX(155);
                    $pdf->Cell(20,5,'Withdrawl', 0,0,'R');
                    $pdf->SetX(175);
                    $pdf->Cell(20,5,'Balance', 0,1,'R');
                    $pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0);

                    $startmonth = $currentmonth;
                }

                //Create line Variables
                $tdate = date('m/d/Y',strtotime($ledger[0]));
                $tdescription = $ledger[2];
                if($ledger[3]==0)   $tdeposit = ""; else $tdeposit = "$".number_format($ledger[3], 2, '.', ',');
                if($ledger[4]==0)   $twithdrawl = ""; else $twithdrawl = "($".-1*number_format($ledger[4], 2, '.', ',').")";
                $runningbal = "$".number_format($balforward + $ledger[5], 2, '.', ',');

                $pdf->Cell(30,7,$tdate, 0,0,'L',1);
                $pdf->SetX(30);
                $pdf->Cell(105,7,$tdescription, 0,0,'L',1);
                $pdf->SetX(135);
                $pdf->Cell(20,7,$tdeposit, 0,0,'R',1);
                $pdf->SetX(155);
                $pdf->Cell(20,7,$twithdrawl, 0,0,'R',1);
                $pdf->SetX(175);
                $pdf->Cell(20,7,$runningbal, 0,1,'R',1);

                if ($grey == 1)
                {
                    $pdf->SetFillColor(255);
                    $grey = 0;
                }
                else $grey = 1;



            }
            //Create Final balance
            $pdf->SetFillColor(255);
            $pdf->SetX(175);
            $pdf->SetFont('','B');
            $pdf->Cell(20,5,'Ending Balance: '.$runningbal, 0,1,'R',1);
            $pdf->SetFont('');
        }                   
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Hi Jared Meyering, Did you solve the problem? please Do you have the whole code? I want to create and send via email multiples pdf using fdpdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is correct, but you may need to restructure your logic.

In each of the files you include, you would want to write functions that to the work of generating the PDF and sending the email. Then your loop can be redone to look like this:

```
require("generatepdf.php"); 
require("ledgeremail.php");

while ($data = mysql_fetch_row($query)) // under normal circumstances working properly
{
    $clientid = $data['0'];
    if($clientid)
    {
        $cname = generate_pdf_for_client( $clientid ); // calls a function in generatepdf.php
        $savepath = 'c:/ledgers/'.$cname.' Cash Ledger.pdf';
        $pdf->Output($savepath,'F');
        send_email_to_client(some appropriate parameters); // calls a function in ledgeremail.php
    }
}
```

So, in your files, you need to implement the logic for the proposed `generate_pdf_for_client` and `send_email_to_client` functions.

Comment: Okay so I created the functions as listed here, however when I run them, they are not outputting anything as they were before. Possibly `$pdf->Output($savepath,'F')` doesn't actually know what to output when the $pdf instance isnt created in actual preceding code? When I place that code inside of the function it will process the first ledger still, but not move on to the next records. I'm starting to think its an issue with `$pdf` I've tried unsetting the instance before continuing with the loop but still no luck.

Comment: Without seeing what your PDF generator does, it is hard to tell what's going on. The gist of the suggestion in the answer is to encapsulate the functional responsibilities of each of the tasks. You could potentially return the PDF object from your generate_pdf call rather than re-using a single instance everytime. Seems like that is what you are doing.

Comment: I added the my pdf generator information, its mostly styling functions of the fpdf class

Comment: Yeah it does. I had an idea at home I'm going to test when I'm back to work tomorrow. I'll just try outputting two simple fpdf documents back to back and see if is an issue with fpdf itself or my code...

Comment: Appreciate your feedback. I ended up rewriting everything, working on my knowledge of oo programming and encapsulating these functions. It works now.